# Can crafted items become ancient?

Tags: diablo-iii

Recently, Diablo 3 introduced "Ancient Legendaries", which can drop on various difficulties on Level 70. It basically works like Warforged in WoW, as it increases the item level it normally has, leading to increased maximum stats on the item.

But can any crafted legendaries become "Ancient" actually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, going forward, any newly crafted legendaries at level 70 can be ancient.  It is, in fact, a simple way to boost your stats.  If you're wearing any crafted legendaries, just craft it again until you get an ancient version.

Note that the plan itself doesn't need to be level 70; any legendary crafted at a higher level than the plan will give you a legendary at your level.  Ancient legendaries can only happen at level 70.

Comment: Also note that you have to be level 70 for a chance to get an ancient version of a legendary at the time of crafting the item.

Comment: Oh, right, missed that part.